# Winter Bash Profile icon twice

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Is it normal to get `wb-hat-count` twice on profile when you get new badge?

[image]

Both links are fully operational.

Is it bug, feature or Easter Egg?

**EDIT:**

This icon probably does not show when new rep level is reached but it shows for `bronze-badge`:

[image]

Comment: Seems like a bug to me.  Curious, though.

Comment: Nice hat collection btw!

Comment: meta.se duplicate: [Double hats on profile page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271607)